# How to create a key on Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having problem on key it says the part of my `markup: Documents.map(this.renderImage)` needed a key but I dont know how will I add a key, I hope someone can help me

```
renderFile(item, i) {
        let items = [];
        let {Documents} = item[i];
        // TODO: i
        items.push({
            id: item[0].Key,
            icon: 'fa fa-file-image-o', //file-pdf-o, file-word-o, excel
            iconTheme: 'bg-purple',
            time: this.renderDate(Documents[0].DateTime, 'D MMM YYYY h:mm A'),
            header: {
                url: '#',
                title:' Uploaded File/s '
            },
            body: {
                content: '',
                markup: Documents.map(this.renderImage)
            }
        })
        return items[0];
    }
```

the map is from here

```
renderImage(i,d) {
    debugger

    var Link= i.Link;
    var file = i.Name;
    let baseApi = this.props.lenk('files/');

    // Inline CSS
    var divStyle = {
        fontSize:"90px"
    };
    var imgStyle = {
         width:"100px",
         height:"100px"
    };
    var box = {
        display: 'inline-block',
        marginLeft:'10px',
        width:"120px",
        height:"120px"
    };
    var divDate = {
        fontSize:"12px"
    };

    if(i.User.AccessRoleKey == 1){
        var User ="primary"
    }
    else if(i.User.AccessRoleKey != 1){
        var User ="info";
    }

    let fileName = ( <EllipsisText text={file} length={20} />  );
    let ext = file.split(".").slice(-1)[0];

    if(ext === "png" || ext === "PNG" || ext === "jpg") {
        return (
            <div style={box}>
            <li key ={i.Key}>
                    <BPicture src={`${ baseApi}/${ Link}`}>
                        <img style={imgStyle} src={`${ baseApi}/${ Link}`} />
                        <span className="text-primary"> {fileName} </span> <br/>    
                    </BPicture>

                    <span style={divDate}> <b>Uploaded by : </b>  </span> <br/>
                    <span className={"label label-" + User}> { ' ' + i.User.FirstName + ' ' + i.User.LastName}</span><br/>
                    <span style={divDate}><b>Date </b> 
                    {i.DateTime} </span>
            </li>
            </div>  
            )
        }
    if(ext === "doc" || ext === "docx") {
        return (
            <div  style={box}> 
            <li key ={i.key}>
            <a href={`${ baseApi}/${ Link}`} >
            <i className="fa fa-file-word-o" style={divStyle}></i><br/>
                 {fileName} </a><br/>
                    <span style={divDate}> <b>Uploaded by : </b>  </span> <br/>
                    <span className={"label label-" + User}> { ' ' + i.User.FirstName + ' ' + i.User.LastName}</span><br/>
                    <span style={divDate}><b>Date </b> 
                    {i.DateTime} </span>
            </li>
            </div>
             )
        }
    if(ext === "pdf" || ext === "pdf") {
        return (
            <div  style={box}>  
            <li key ={i.key}>
            <a className="text-danger" href={`${ baseApi}/${ Link}`} >
            <i className="fa fa-file-pdf-o" style={divStyle}></i><br/></a>
                 <a href={`${ baseApi}/${ Link}`}> {fileName} </a><br/>
                 <span style={divDate}> <b>Uploaded by : </b>  </span> <br/>
                    <span className={"label label-" + User}> { ' ' + i.User.FirstName + ' ' + i.User.LastName}</span><br/>
                    <span style={divDate}><b>Date </b> 
                    {i.DateTime} </span>
                    </li>
            </div>
               )
            }
    if(ext === "xlsx" || ext === "xls") {
        return (
            <div  style={box}>
            <li key ={i.key}>
            <a className="text-success" href={`${ baseApi}/${ Link}`} >
            <i className="fa fa-file-excel-o" style={divStyle}></i> <br/> </a>
                 <a href={`${ baseApi}/${ Link}`} > {fileName} </a> <br/>
                 <span style={divDate}> <b>Uploaded by : </b>  </span> <br/>
                    <span className={"label label-" + User}> { ' ' + i.User.FirstName + ' ' + i.User.LastName}</span><br/>
                    <span style={divDate}><b>Date </b> 
                    {i.DateTime} </span>
                    </li>
            </div>
              )
        }
}
```

Comment: we need to see your renderImage function

Comment: @hairmot updated

Comment: @LAGIM: Full function update please

Comment: @FiriceNguyen updated

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about react warning in a console? If you are using `map` you need to add `key` prop to each element. Keys help React identify which items have changed. Read more about [keys](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) in official documentation.

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
  <li key={number.toString()}>
    {number}
  </li>
);
```

Comment: ive seen that but i dont know   what to i updated the question I hope you get it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-key-index` package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-key-index

Comment: not really working for me.. i tried `var data = keyIndex(data, 1);` and changed  `<div key={data.key}  style={box}> ` but my map wont work

Answer (score 0):

Just add up to @mradziwon answer. In your `renderImage`, you just only need to add `key` at your top element in `render`. It would be your `<div  style={box}>`. Update it to `<div key={i.key}  style={box}>` to the top `div` of every `return` block

Comment: I dont get it... sorry please explain